# Typing "/" in windows explorer brings up Firefox error

Tags: windows-7, firefox, windows-explorer

when I type a "/" (forward slash) in windows 7 file browser (explorer.exe), and hit enter, it brings up a Firefox error, saying "Couldn't load XPCOM". Why does this have anything to do with Firefox? Firefox works just fine.

[image: (screenshot of error)]

Comment: When you type `/` alone in explorer, it assumes you are trying to access a website.  In response, it would try to open on your default browser.  Cant say I know what causes this specific error but I will let you know if I find anything.

Comment: @CheesusCrust thanks! that is probably all it is then. The error will be some other thing then!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you enter a forward slash `"/"` into the file explorer, it is considered a URL.
This will then prompt the Explorer to open the provided URL in your default browser.

As for the error Firefox returns; I found an [article on Mozilla's forums](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1029239) that walks through a fix, although its not exactly innovative...

> Do a clean reinstall and delete the Firefox program folder before (re)installing a fresh copy of the current Firefox release.
>
> Download the full Firefox installer and save the file to the desktop
>   https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/all/ If possible uninstall your
>   current Firefox version to cleanup the Windows registry and settings
>   in security software.
>
> **Do NOT** remove "personal data" when you uninstall your current Firefox
>   version, because this will remove all profile folders and you lose
>   personal data like bookmarks and passwords including data in profiles
>   created by other Firefox versions. Remove the Firefox program folder
>   before installing that newly downloaded copy of the Firefox installer.
>
> (32 bit Windows) "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\"
>
> (64 bit Windows) "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\"
>
> **It is important to delete the Firefox program folder to remove all the files and make sure that
>   there are no problems with files that were leftover after
>   uninstalling.** 
>   http://kb.mozillazine.org/Uninstalling_Firefox
>
> Your bookmarks and other personal data are stored in the Firefox profile
>   folder and won't be affected by an uninstall and (re)install, but make
>   sure NOT to remove personal data when you uninstall Firefox as that
>   will remove all Firefox profile folders and you lose your personal
>   data.